# How to read OLE Object of Package Part for reading of embedded zip file in java?

Tags: java, zip, ole, bytearrayinputstream

HI I am new comer java developer of OLE Object of Package Part. i am facing issue about to read embedded zip from docx file in my current project.
I have read docx file and get package part to read embedded object . it returns PackagePart class.

We need to read a zip file which has some excel files. 
I am confuse that how to read it to get data from excel files.

i am using some code to do this.: -

```
PackagePart pPart = null;
         Iterator<PackagePart> pIter = null;
         List<PackagePart> embeddedDocs = document.getAllEmbedds();
         if (embeddedDocs != null && !embeddedDocs.isEmpty()) 
         {
             pIter = embeddedDocs.iterator();
             while (pIter.hasNext()) 
             {
                 pPart = pIter.next();
                //System.out.println(pPart.getPartName().getExtension());


                 System.out.println(pPart.getInputStream());


             }
         }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**This code provides us some output like**

```
java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@2862c542
java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@6c8484c4
java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@70289784
java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@78f394a2
```

**It is possible that we can read data from attached zip in docx file ?

can we save all data from zip to my hard disk ?**

Please help me 
Thanks to interest.